Why do some links work correctly and others throw errors?
   private void SearchBar_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        StringComparison comparison = StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase;
        ItemsListView.ItemsSource = _viewModel.Tools.Where(x => x.ProductIndex.StartsWith(e.NewTextValue, comparison));
    }

I get: System.Refelction.TargetInvocationExcecption. InnerException show: System.NullReferenceException and Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
I tried use "Contains()" but result was the same.
This code was work good 2 months ago. It is because xamarin is out of support? (Support Ended 1 May 2024 but even after that it was working correctly).

No, it's because you have an entry in your Tools list where ProductIndex is null. Check where/ how you are populating your Tools list

My list and fields (ProductIndex) aren't null. I get this error when I use some kind of linqs: like StartWith or Contains. For example when I used in linq:  "ItemsListView.ItemsSource = _viewModel.Tools.Where(x => x.Id > 100).ToList();" - it works correctly.
